# what data sources do smart markers accept?

Tags: aspose-cells

I am using aspose cells with java. I want know what data sources do smart markers support. I know java objects are one of them. What others can be given?

> &=DataSource.FieldName
>   &=[Data Source].[Field Name]

Answer (score 0):

You may set JAVA ResultSet, variable, variable arrays, custom class objects, etc. as data source for Smart Markers.

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose